# Sunday Algorithm - Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#

I have this Sunday Algorithm, which checks some occurrences in some text.

```
class Program
{
    static int alphabet = 512;
    static int[] table = new int[alphabet];

    static int[] occurence(string pattern)
    {
        for(char a = (char)0; a<(char)alphabet;a++)
        {
            table[(int)a] = -1;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i< pattern.Length;i++)
        {
            char a = pattern[i];
            table[(int)a] = i;
        }
        return table;
    }

    public static int Sunday(string text, string pattern)
    {
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();
        int k = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int[] table = new int[pattern.Length];
        table = occurence(pattern);
        while(i <= text.Length - pattern.Length)
        {
            int j = 0;
            while(j<pattern.Length && text[i+j] == pattern[j])
            {
                j++;
            }
            if(j==pattern.Length)
            {
                k++;
            }
            i += pattern.Length;
            if(i<text.Length)
            {
                i -= table[(int)text[i]];
            }
        }
        timer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed);
        return k;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Bacho\Desktop\Studies\Advanced Algorithms\Test Patterns\Book1.txt");
        string pattern = "frankenstein";
        Console.WriteLine(Sunday(text, pattern));
    }
}
```

This is my algorithm, which works well on small input of text. In the code, I try to read a text file which consists of roughly 80 000 words and 450 000 characters. I get this exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>      at Sunday1.Program.Sunday(String text, String pattern) in C:\Users\Bacho\Desktop\Studies\Advanced Algorithms\Sunday1\Sunday1\Program.cs:line 55
>      at Sunday1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Bacho\Desktop\Studies\Advanced Algorithms\Sunday1\Sunday1\Program.cs:line 68

..at the following line:

```
i -= table[(int)text[i]];
```

Is it because it can not fit in string or is it something else?

Changing the algorithm to read and check line by line may be a solution, but is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: When you post a debugging question that includes an exception, you should also mention the line that causes the exception to occur. Based on the line number, I added that line to your post. Please feel free to correct that if I got the wrong line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `char` has a length of two bytes or 16 bits not 9. So I guess your `alphabet` should therefore probably be `65336` or simply `char.MaxValue` instead of `512`.

Also there's no need of the static fields. You can make them local to `occurence()`. And in Sunday, you don't need to initialize `table` with `new int[pattern.Length]`, you can directly use `occurence(pattern)`.

```
class Program
{
    static int[] occurence(string pattern)
    {
        int[] table = new int[char.MaxValue + 1];

        for (int a = 0; a < char.MaxValue + 1; a++)
        {
            table[a] = -1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < pattern.Length; i++)
        {
            char a = pattern[i];
            table[(int)a] = i;
        }
        return table;
    }

    public static int Sunday(string text, string pattern)
    {
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();
        int k = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int[] table = occurence(pattern);
        while (i <= text.Length - pattern.Length)
        {
            int j = 0;
            while (j < pattern.Length && text[i + j] == pattern[j])
            {
                j++;
            }
            if (j == pattern.Length)
            {
                k++;
            }
            i += pattern.Length;
            if (i < text.Length)
            {
                i -= table[(int)text[i]];
            }
        }
        timer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed);
        return k;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Bacho\Desktop\Studies\Advanced Algorithms\Test Patterns\Book1.txt");
        string pattern = "frankenstein";
        Console.WriteLine(Sunday(text, pattern));
    }
}
```